# class ProfilePresenter < ActionView::Base | url_for doesn't work. why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class ProfilePresenter < ActionView::Base 
 def initialize
  super
  url_for   # i got: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
            #        The error occurred while evaluating nil.url_for
 end
end
```

url_for doesn't work. why?

i make a new instance like this

```
ProfilePresenter.new
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: i need to pass the controller instance when i instance the ActionView::Base